# I want to host laravel 9 project on cpanel but getting 404 not found

Tags: laravel, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting, laravel-9

I have been trying for 3 days still didn't find any solution of it. I have tried so many solution still remained same.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here my laravel project is in the public_html. I am sharing a screenshot so that you guys can figure out the issue.

[image]

Here is the live of my website: https://kothay-jaben.com/

Comment: A way to workaround it is to move the contents of the ```public``` folder to ```public_html``` and then move the laravel files to a new folder inside ```public_html``` and edit the ```index.php``` file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy your laravel project, you should leav the directory structure intact.
So, the project should not be inside `public_html`.
Upload all files adn directories one level up (out side `public_html`).
Then do one of the follwoing:

1. copy/move files from `public` to `public_html`
2. Make a symlink from `public_html`

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess files usually go into the 'public' folder of laravel app. Try moving that.

Answer (score -1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<Files .env>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?